# ListView of cameras in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties

I'm trying to make a ListView of cameras form my WPF application.

First, I made it with [WPFMediaKit](http://wpfmediakit.codeplex.com/), but I had a unacceptable performance issues with black blinks and low framerates.

Now I'm trying with [AvCapWPF](http://wpfcap.codeplex.com/), but I can't figure out how to bind the device to the player. I modified CapPlayer.cs with a DependencyProperty, but all my players show the same camera.

Here is some code:

```
   private void Current_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _device = new CapDevice(DevicePath);
    _device.OnNewBitmapReady += new EventHandler(_device_OnNewBitmapReady);
}

 public static readonly DependencyProperty DevicePathProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("DevicePath", typeof(string), 
            typeof(CapPlayer), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(string)));

public string DevicePath
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(DevicePathProperty); }
    set { SetValue(DevicePathProperty, value); }
}
```

`DevicePath` is different every time the debugger stops on

```
_device = new CapDevice(DevicePath);
```

Any suggestions?